# Applying images on top of a background image

Tags: html, css, image

I seem to be having problems with my CSS code. I want to have a background image at `100%` of the page `width` and `height`, and then other images strategically placed on top of the background image. The problem I am having is that when I absolutely place the images on top, unless I specify an actual height of the background image, the actual image does not show up in the background. Can anyone suggest a way around actually specifying a height for the background image?

```css
#map {
  background-image: url("images/middleearth_map.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#registermap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
}

#gollum {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 15%;
}

#playtrailer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  <div id="registermap">
    <a href="register.html">
      <img src="images/middle-earth_map1.png" alt="Registration Link" class="wobble" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="gollum">
    <a href="cast.html">
      <img src="images/gollum.png" alt="Cast and Crew Link" class="wobble" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="playtrailer">
    <a href="trailer.html">
      <img src="images/play_button.png" alt="Movie Trailer Link" class="wobble" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please upload images for your demo?

Comment: _"I want to have a background image at 100% of the page width and height"_ - really? You know that is going to stretch the image, disregarding its original aspect ratio? For a map of some sorts, that is a rather strange demand. Plus, it _generates_ much the problem you are dealing with - your absolute element positions are depending on the viewport, so they are not undergoing the same transposition the "elements" that are on your distorted map are subjected to. I think you will need to either choose background-size `contain` or `cover`, before this even allows for a halfway trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with ***map*** id not fill all the window size, Change the **css** to this:

```
#map {
  background-image: url("images/middleearth_map.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I have only ever used px or % in my css code before. Can you explain what the vw and vh mean please.

Comment: @shakarn7 `vw` (`viewport-width`) – percent of screen width, `100vw` means `100%` of screen width, `vh` (`viewport-height`) – percent of of screen height, `100vh` means `100%` of screen height.

Comment: So I tried this, but the background image doesn't cover 100% of the web browser page when I scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `background-image` for `body` to be sure that it occupies all window.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JzYG.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%; /* Picture stretches */
  min-height: 100vh; /* Body occupies at least all screen */
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: If I use min-height: 100vh it will only stretch to the viewing area, not 100% of the web browser.

Comment: Body will be stretched by its content. At least should if your doing everything right.

Comment: @shakarn7 see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypy27L14/1/) how it will look like when we have scroll in our `body`.

Comment: I tried changing the css to body but the background image won't stretch. In order for it to fill the entire web browser I have to take off the no-repeat, but then it repeats, not stretches, obviously. I think it is because of the absolutely positioned images after the body. I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @shakarn7 Can you add/upload images to your demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on JSFiddle. Must be something I have done.